# Do Something when user answer the call and when user close the call and how to close the call

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I use this code to call :

```
Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel://911");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,callUri);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

i would like to do something when user close the call

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can use a flag(boolean)which is by default false. set flag=true when you call and in `onResume()` if(flag){ do some stuff and make flag=false}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, register the following permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Then, a BroadcastReceiver called OutCallLogger that catches the `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` event whenever an outgoing call is made

Register your receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.OutCallLogger">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Next, implementation of OutCallLogger. set up a boolean called noCallListenerYet to avoid attaching a new PhoneStateListener to the TelephonyManager whenever onReceive() is invoked.

```
public class OutCallLogger extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static boolean noCallListenerYet = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if (noCallListenerYet) {
            final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    switch (state) {
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "RINGING");
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "IDLE");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.d(This.LOG_TAG, "Default: " + state);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            noCallListenerYet = false;
        }
    }
```

Here `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:` state is called when user press end call.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This would be always called, even the user presses end call or not, phone would go to the IDLE state for sure.